# Value of msg.sender is not changing after specifying {from} in truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle

Given two contracts :

```
contract First {
  function cSender() public view returns(address){
    return msg.sender; 
  }
}

contract Second {
  First f;
  function Second() public {
    f = new First(); 
  }

  function checkSender(uint t) public view returns(address){
    t = 0; 
    return f.cSender();
  }
}
```

truffle command:

```
Second.deployed().then(function(inst) {
  return inst.checkSender(10, { 
    from: "0x5aeda56215b167893e80b4fe645ba6d5bab767de" 
  })
});
```

But here I am not getting `from` as `msg.sender` value, instead getting contract address. Why? How to get `from` as value?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calling the function `cSender` defined in the contract `First` from your contract `Second`.So it will return contract address of the `Second` contract.

there are two possible solutions inorder to get the `from` param defined in truffle.

1)Define the function `cSender` in the contract `Second`.

2)Use the same contract structure and update the `msg.sender` with `tx.origin` .

Note :-
`msg.sender` gives the direct sender of the message, so for example a contract that passed it along.

`tx.origin` gives the origin of the transactions, so the user address it was originally sent from.

3) The contract `Second` would pass its `from` address to `first` is another possible solution.